# Load in content to popup box when the popup opens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script to have a popup box with some setting in my site:

http://codeissue.com/articles/a04daf3210c8b0a/cross-browser-modal-popup-using-javascript-jquery

The popup opens when click a button/text:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ShowModalPopup('name_of_div_in_popup_box'); return false;">Text</a>
```

I wonder if its possible to load the content (`#name_of_div_in_popup_box`) into the popup box from a external page (in same website) instead of have the div hidden in all the pages woth this popup box. The problem is that the popup is in many pages so in the current situation I have to paste `#name_of_div_in_popup_box` in every page that have the popup and when doing a edit in that div I have to do the edits in all pages.

Easier to load the content to the popup box from a external page example content.html #name_of_div_in_popup_box so when making a change to the div I only have to make the change in that site.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot access other files on the server (except perhaps using AJAX) as it is client side. However if you use a php or shtml include this should allow you to access the file from the web pages that need it without having to add the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#name_of_div_in_popup_box').load('load_from_this_page.html');
```

> Additional Notes:
>
> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.